# Is this a sign of stunted growth (on tomato seedlings)?

Tags: tomatoes, growth

I germinated this batch of heirloom Tiny Tim tomatoes, and have been told that they start off really slow. It's been a month now. There are a couple of them that has a swollen stem like in the picture, and their growth seems to be stunted. I've never seen anything like this before, and it feels like all the nutrients the seedling absorbed are just sitting in that swollen stem. What's really happening here? And is there a fix for this?

[image: Tiny Tim Tomato 1]

[image: Tiny Tim Tomato 2]

Comment: Off the top, the soil looks extremely wet. First, I'd back off on the water. The soil should be damp but not soaked. Seedlings need very little water at this stage. Second, are you supplementing with fertilizer? The seed has enough nutrients to get to those first set of true leaves, but you need to start feeding soon after. Tomatoes grow quite rapidly and quite readily so my guess is overwatering plus lack of nutrients.